# Visual Studio 2015 + libtcod - Unexpected exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, libtcod

I am having an odd issue getting libtcod to work with Visual Studio 2015.

I have followed all the steps found on this [blog post](http://daraprogramming.blogspot.ca/2014/08/setting-up-libtcod-151-with-visual.html) to get everything linked.

The problem is that during **debugging or running it inside Visual Studio** the application will always close at initRoot with exit code 1, no other information or errors.

Running the produced EXE outside of Visual Studio has no issues whatsoever - starts up and works as expected!

The only information I could find related to this was a [forum post that turned ugly in 2012](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/forum/index.php?topic=1530.0)

I did make a modification to the blog post's code to include a setCustomFont as well, which did not change anything.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be going on?

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "libtcod.hpp"

// Hide the console window
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")

int main()
{
    TCODConsole::setCustomFont("terminal12x12_gs_ro.png", TCOD_FONT_LAYOUT_ASCII_INROW | TCOD_FONT_TYPE_GRAYSCALE);
    TCODConsole::initRoot(80, 50, "C++ libtcod tutorial");
    TCODConsole::root->printEx(40, 25, TCOD_BKGND_NONE, TCOD_CENTER, "Hello world");
    TCODConsole::flush();
    TCODConsole::waitForKeypress(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles upon this later, the above blog post is correct for setting up the vast majority of the application - if you run into the same issue I did (crashing / exiting in initRoot) make sure you have the terminal png in the source directory, this is what fixed it for me.